# Regex : extracting a decimal number preceded by a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. 
I have lines in a text file...the target lines look like this

> - Nsource.Inhibitor    3   81.63   27.21   1.84    0.008
> - Nsource.Inhibitor    3   90.31   17.21   0.84    <0.001

I want to extract the 0.008 and <0.001 from the end.

However, there are other lines that mean we have to use the first part of the line as part of a pattern....

> - Nsource  1   1238.10     1238.10     40.29  <.001
> - Inhibitor    3   1484.41     494.80  16.10  <.001

My attempt

```
reline <- "+ Nsource.Inhibitor   3   81.63   27.21   1.84    0.008"
decnum <- "[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*"
chk <- paste0("+ Nsource.Inhibitor[:blank:]+", decnum, "[:blank:]+", decnum, "[:blank:]+", decnum, "[:blank:]+", decnum,
       "[:blank:]+", "([[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*)")
gsub(chk, "\\1",reline)
```

returns:

> "+ Nsource.Inhibitor\t 3\t 81.63\t 27.21\t 1.84\t 0.008"

Thanks for your help.

Matt

Comment: What does *use the first part of the line as part of a pattern*? Please explain what you need to extract and what exactly is the expected output for all of your sample inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(stringr)
strings <- c("Nsource.Inhibitor 3 81.63 27.21 1.84 0.008", "Nsource.Inhibitor 3 90.31 17.21 0.84 <0.001", 
             "Nsource 1 1238.10 1238.10 40.29 <.001", "Inhibitor 3 1484.41 494.80 16.10 <.001")

str_match(strings, "(?=^Nsource.Inhibitor).*?(<?\\d+\\.\\d+)$")[,2]
```

This yields

```
[1] "0.008"  "<0.001" NA       NA
```

It ensures, there's `Nsource.Inhibitor` at the start of the string and only then matches the last `\d+.\d+` pattern of that line (plus `<` eventually).

Comment: really simple solution, but missing the "<" -- which I can add back later, I guess.

Comment: @user2449710: Changed the answer - make it lazy and you'll get the desired results in one rush (no adding back later, that is).

Answer (score 1):

If your target lines contain "Nsource.Inhibitor" and the last character is a number, and you want to extract all the characters after the last space, then try:

```
gsub(".*Nsource\\.Inhibitor.*\\s(.*[0-9])$", "\\1", reline)
```

You could add `ignore.case = T` if `Nsource` or `Inhibitor` appear without caps.

Examples:

```
> reline <- "+ Nsource.Inhibitor   3   81.63   27.21   1.84    <0.008"
> output <- gsub(".*Nsource\\.Inhibitor.*\\s(.*[0-9])$", "\\1", reline, ignore.case = T)
> output
[1] "<0.008"

> reline <- "+ Nsource.Inhibitor   3   81.11  27  1232   23  123111  55.5555  0.38"
> output <- gsub(".*Nsource\\.inhibitor.*\\s(.*[0-9])$", "\\1", reline, ignore.case = T)
> output
[1] "0.38"
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The last "word" can be a number or "<001".

Answer (score 1):

```
strings <- c("Nsource.Inhibitor 3 81.63 27.21 1.84 0.008", "Nsource.Inhibitor 3 90.31 17.21 0.84 <0.001",  "Nsource 1 1238.10 1238.10 40.29 <.001", "Inhibitor 3 1484.41 494.80 16.10 <.001")
```

The expression below uses grep to pick up strings that contain substring 'Nsource.Inhibitor', splits the string by `' '`, and returns the the 6th element of each of the splitted strings.

```
sapply(strsplit(strings[grep('Nsource.Inhibitor', strings)], ' '), '[[',6)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for using regex here. Simply read the file as a data.frame and do simple subsetting:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Nsource.Inhibitor 3 81.63 27.21 1.84 0.008
           Nsource.Inhibitor 3 90.31 17.21 0.84 <0.001
           Nsource 1 1238.10 1238.10 40.29 <.001
           nhibitor 3 1484.41 494.80 16.10 <.001", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #you can read from file directly

DF[DF$V1 == "Nsource.Inhibitor", ncol(DF)]
#[1] "0.008"  "<0.001"
```